# Is there a way to use DATA_BLOB in python?

Tags: python, winapi

so I created a C++ DLL file and I'd like to use it in python that's not my problem. My problem is the return type of the DLL functions, I have 2 function, both of them return [DATA_BLOB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/aa381414(v=vs.85)) and I didn't find a way that I could use [DATA_BLOB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/aa381414(v=vs.85)) in python, my question is how can I use [DATA_BLOB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/aa381414(v=vs.85)) in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of a DLL function is generally the result of a function execution. If you need to return data, put it in the parameters, and use the pointer.

DLL Sample:

```
BOOL DLLCall1(PDATA_BLOB DataOut) //return DATA_BLOB pointer
{
    DATA_BLOB DataIn;
    BYTE* pbDataInput = (BYTE*)"Hello world of data protection.";
    DWORD cbDataInput = strlen((char*)pbDataInput) + 1;

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Initialize the DataIn structure.

    DataIn.pbData = pbDataInput;
    DataIn.cbData = cbDataInput;

    CryptProtectData(
        &DataIn,
        L"This is the description string.", // A description string
                                            // to be included with the
                                            // encrypted data. 
        NULL,                               // Optional entropy not used.
        NULL,                               // Reserved.
        NULL,                               // Pass NULL for the 
                                            // prompt structure.
        0,
        DataOut);


    return 1;
}

BOOL DLLCall2(DATA_BLOB DataOut)
{
    LPWSTR pDescrOut = NULL;
    DATA_BLOB DataVerify;
    CRYPTPROTECT_PROMPTSTRUCT PromptStruct;
    ZeroMemory(&PromptStruct, sizeof(PromptStruct));
    PromptStruct.cbSize = sizeof(PromptStruct);
    PromptStruct.dwPromptFlags = CRYPTPROTECT_PROMPT_ON_PROTECT;
    PromptStruct.szPrompt = L"This is a user prompt.";
    if (CryptUnprotectData(
        &DataOut,
        &pDescrOut,
        NULL,                 // Optional entropy
        NULL,                 // Reserved
        &PromptStruct,        // Optional PromptStruct
        0,
        &DataVerify))
    {
        printf("The decrypted data is: %s\n", DataVerify.pbData);
        printf("The description of the data was: %S\n", pDescrOut);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

python:

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import DWORD
import ctypes

class DATA_BLOB(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("cbData", DWORD),
        ("pbData", POINTER(c_char)),
    ]
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("C:\\Test.dll")
blobOut = DATA_BLOB()
lib.DLLCall1(byref(blobOut))
lib.DLLCall2(blobOut)
```

Comment: Thank you I already solved it I forgot to upload my solution I basically did the same thing for some reason when I tried sending it to my c++ DLL function in C++ it said that the parameter is incorrect(I give the DLL Data_in not out)